# Conic programming: optimality conditions

Tags: convex-optimization, dual-cone

I am trying to derive the optimality conditions of a conic program which is a minimization problem in the form:
$$
\mathrm{Minimize}_{x,s} c'x\\
s\in C\\
Ax + s =  b.
$$
Here $C$ is a cone with nonempty relative interior.
But I would like to do so using the subdifferential-based Fermat's theorem which states that for a convex lower-semicontinuous function $F:\Re^n\to\Re\cup\{+\infty\}$, the optimization problem
$$
\mathrm{Minimize}_x F(x),
$$
has the optimality condition $0\in\partial F(x)$.

I am trying to apply this theorem to the conic problem above and derive the standard (primal-dual) optimality conditions. For that, I defined the function 
$F(x) = c'x + \delta_C(b-Ax)$, where $\delta_C$ is the indicator function of $C$, so the first-order optimality conditions become

$$
0\in \partial (c'x + \delta_C(b-Ax)) = c - A' (\partial \delta_C)(b-Ax)
$$

equivalently

$$
c \in A' (\partial \delta_C)(b-Ax)
$$

or

$$
c = A'y\\
y \in \partial \delta_C(b-Ax) = N_C(b-Ax),
$$

where $N_C$ is the normal cone of $C$.

At the same time, it is quite standard that the primal-dual optimality conditions of the above conic problem are:

$$
b - Ax \in C\\
y \in C^*\\
A'y + c = 0\\
c'x + b'y = 0,
$$

where $C^*=\{z: z'x\geq 0, x \in C\}$ is the dual cone of $C$.

I can't see how to solve the above optimality conditions to yield these standard optimality conditions. I don't know how to go from $N_C$ to a term involving $C^*$.

Comment: I think it should it be $0 \in c - A^T \partial \delta_c(b - Ax)$.  Also, tangential question --- what is the "Slater's condition" that you need here in order to conclude that the subdifferential of the sum is the sum of the subdifferentials?

Comment: @littleO Thanks for pointing these issues out. I need to assume that $C$ has a nonempty relative interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the following identity which can be found in Hiriart-Urruty and Lemaréchal's book "Fundamentals of Convex Analysis," ex. 5.2.6:

$$
N_C(z) = C^\circ \cap \{z\}^\perp,
$$

where $C^\circ$ is the polar of $C$. Can you take it from there?